# Get an entity by a key passed via GET parameter

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, go

I have

```
http://localhost:8080/?key=ahFkZXZ-ZGV2LWVkdW5hdGlvbnIOCxIIVXNlckluZm8YLAw
```

I would like to ask on how to:

1. Decode and convert the "key" to a `*datastore.Key`
2. And use it to get an entity.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You should add more tags to this question. (Go and gae-datastore)

Comment: It's also nice if you could show us what you have tried before asking :) (this is btw. a trivial problem which is easy to solve)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First: You should think about *which* packages you need this case. Since you're trying to read a `GET` value from a `URL` you need probably a function from [`net/http`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/).
In particular: [`FormValue(key string)`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.FormValue) returns `GET` and `POST` parameters.

Second: Now open the [`appengine/datastore`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference) documentation and find  functions which do the following:

- Decode a `string` to a `*datastore.Key` ([DecodeKey(encoded string)](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference#DecodeKey))
- Get a specified key from the datastore ([Get(c appengine.Context, key *Key, dst interface{})](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference#Get))

Now it's a really easy thing:

```
func home(w http.Response, r *http.Request) {
    c := appengine.NewContext(r)

    // Get the key from the URL
    keyURL := r.FormValue("key")

    // Decode the key
    key, err := datastore.DecodeKey(keyURL)
    if err != nil { // Couldn't decode the key
        // Do some error handling
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    // Get the key and load it into "data"
    var data Data
    err = datastore.Get(c, key, data)
    if err != nil { // Couldn't find the entity
        // Do some error handling
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all your help. It is nice that someone gets answer quickly.

Comment: @user1949730 Please accept answers as "accepted" if they solved your problem. (http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Comment: You should check the error returned from DecodeKey (well, you should always check errors if the operation could fail, which is certainly the case when you're decoding user input).

Comment: My URL is something like https://testapp.appspot.com/api/authorized.url#access_token=123456789 not sure how to fetch access_token now. Note that if its ? at the place of # then its working fine using r.FormValue("access_token")